# Can't use a future string to determine initalRoute

Tags: flutter, dart

My code is like this

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<String> validation() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isWTdone = prefs.getBool('WT') ?? false;
    bool isLoggedIn = prefs.getString('email') == null ? false : true;

    if(isWTdone){
      if(isLoggedIn)
      {
        return '/home';
      }
        return '/login';
    }
      return '/';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorObservers: [
        locator<AnalyticsService>().getanalyticsObserver(),
      ],
      //iswalkthrough and islogin
      initialRoute: validation(),
      routes: appRoutes,
    );
  }
}
```

in the initalRoute line it gives me this error:

> The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String?'.

Can anyone know how can i fix this? my goal is to determine the initalRoute from the output of the SharedPreference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, that's because the method `validation` is a future and to use it you have to write `await validation()` and that cannot be done **directly** inside the widget tree,
a solution I suggest;

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool isWTdone = prefs.getBool('WT') ?? false;
  bool isLoggedIn = prefs.getString('email') == null ? false : true;
  late final initialRoute;

  if (isWTdone) {
    if (isLoggedIn)
      initialRoute = '/home';
    else
      initialRoute = '/login';
  } else
    initialRoute = '/';

  return runApp(MyApp(initialRoute: initialRoute));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String initialRoute;

  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.initialRoute}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorObservers: [
        locator<AnalyticsService>().getanalyticsObserver(),
      ],
      //iswalkthrough and islogin
      initialRoute: validation(),
      routes: appRoutes,
    );
  }
}
```

What I've done here, is I initialized the `initialRoute` before the `runApp` and passed to the `MyApp` Stateless Widget

Comment: ```void main() {
  Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  locator.registerLazySingleton<AnalyticsService>(() => AnalyticsService());

  runApp(const MyFirebaseApp());
}``` My main is like this since I'm using firebase. Do yo know how can integrate your solution with it?

Comment: Yes, modify your `main` function in contain
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool isWTdone = prefs.getBool('WT') ?? false;
  bool isLoggedIn = prefs.getString('email') == null ? false : true;
  late final initialRoute;

  if (isWTdone) {
    if (isLoggedIn)
      initialRoute = '/home';
    else
      initialRoute = '/login';
  } else
    initialRoute = '/';

and then add the parameter `initialRoute` to your `MyFirebaseApp` Widget
Then, `runApp(const MyFirebaseApp(initialRoute));` pass the initial route to your widget

Comment: In this solution you haven't used the validation() function but it's still written on initialroute. Am I missing something or should i write something else instead of validation()?

Comment: Yes, your initial route inside the MaterialApp:  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorObservers: [
        locator<AnalyticsService>().getanalyticsObserver(),
      ],
      //iswalkthrough and islogin
      initialRoute: initialRoute,
      routes: appRoutes,
    );
  }

Comment: Tip @AbdallahA.Odeh: avoid putting much information to comments, update your answer instead and just comment "I updated my answer".

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap MaterialApp to FutureBuilder or perform your async code in main.dart before calling runApp. You can pass needed value to the MyApp through the constructor.

Comment: Can you give me the code example for FutureBuilder? I'm new to flutter and I don't know how to use it.

Comment: FutureBuilder(
            future: validate(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) =>  MaterialApp(
              initialRoute: snapshot.data,
              routes: appRoutes,
            ),
          ),

But I guess it would be better to call SharedPreferences.getInstance() in main.dart before calling runApp() because your MaterialApp will be rendered only after future is completed. And while future is performing, you will see only black screen.
If you call SharedPreference.getInstance() before runApp(), splash screen will be displayed while async code is performing.

Comment: Tip @AlexShinkevich: avoid putting much information to comments, update your answer instead and just comment "I updated my answer".

Answer (score 0):

Set the initialRoute to a route of a Splash Screen. Inside that screen you should call your validation() function inside initState and depending on your output you navigate to whatever screen you want to. I don't think using an async method inside your MaterialApp widget is encouraged so try to implement this inside a Splash Screen and you'll be fine.